# How do I pull only sequences of sentences that have numbers in them?

Tags: string, python-2.7, tokenize

I have a string of text which I've split on periods.

```
sentences = ['The number of adults who read at least one novel within the past 12 months fell to 47%.', 'Fiction reading rose from 2002 to 2008.', 'The decline in fiction reading last year occurred mostly among men.', 'Women read more fiction.', '50% more.', 'Though it decreased 10% over the last decade.', 'Men are more likely to read nonfiction.', 'Young adults are more likely to read fiction.', 'Just 54% of Americans cracked open a book of  any kind last year.', 'But novels have suffered more than nonfiction.']
```

I'd like to extract all sequences of sentences that contain a number in them, along with the sentence right before and right after. So, the outputs should be the following strings:

**"The number of adults who read at least one novel within the past 12 months fell to 47%. Fiction reading rose from 2002 to 2008.The decline in fiction reading last year occurred mostly among men."**

**"Women read more fiction. 50% more. Though it decreased 10% over the last decade. Men are more likely to read nonfiction."**

**"Young adults are more likely to read fiction. Just 54% of Americans cracked open a book of  any kind last year. But novels have suffered more than nonfiction."**

First I find the indexes of all strings with numbers in them:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
indexes = []
for index, sentence in enumerate(sentences):
    if (re.findall('\d+', sentence)):
        indexes.append(index)
```

Break the indexes up by whether they are sequences of indexes or single indexes:

```
index_groupings = []
for k, g in groupby(enumerate(indexes), lambda (i, x): i-x): 
    index_groupings.append(map(itemgetter(1), g))

multiple_sents = [] #store sentence sequences
single_sent = [] #store single sentences
multiple_indexes = [] 
single_index = []
for grouping in index_groupings:
    if len(grouping) > 1:
        multiple_indexes.append(grouping)       
    else:
        single_index.append(grouping)
```

Separate out multiple sentence sequences and single sentences:

```
if multiple_indexes:
    for grouping in multiple_indexes:
        for index in grouping:
            multiple_sents.append(sentences[index])
else:
    pass
if single_index:
    for grouping in single_index:
        for index in grouping:
            single_sent.append(sentences[index])
else:
    pass

print multiple_sents
print single_sent
```

When I print, I get:

['The number of adults who read at least one novel within the past 12 months fell to 47%.', 'Fiction reading rose from 2002 to 2008.', '50% more.', 'Though it decreased 10% over the last decade.']

['Just 54% of Americans cracked open a book of  any kind last year.']

What's the best way to go about joining the sequences that belong with each other to get the desired output above? Is there are cleaner way to do this?

Comment: I would use a state-machine here. You could iterate through the list once and be done. I've thought of the states but haven't fleshed out the algorithm yet. I will if you would like. Just no time atm.

section_state = { section_closed, section_open_no_number_content, section_open_has_number_content }

With only a little thinking, you can flesh out a decision tree that can make your sections, and make sure they meet your requirements.

Comment: Not sure how I'd go about doing that. If you could elaborate with a clean solution, that would be great.